# Terraform outputs for resources with count

Tags: terraform

I have my s3 resource in terraform with configuration:

```
locals {
    bucket_count = "${length(var.s3_config["bucket_names"])}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
    count = "${local.bucket_count}"
    bucket = "${format("%s-%s", element(var.s3_config["bucket_names"], count.index), var.region)}"
    acl = "private"
    region = "${var.region}"

    tags {
        Name = "${format("%s-%s", element(var.s3_config["bucket_names"], count.index), var.region)}"
    }
}
```

and i want to set output variable for all created bucket so i created file names outputs.tf with content

```
output "buckets" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.bucket}"
}

output "buckets_arns" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.arn}"
}
```

when i apply configuration its ok i see outputs in terraform.tfstate file but when i call terraform output i see information that is no output or output is empty what i do wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried: `output "buckets" {
  value = [ "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.bucket}" ]
}`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this:

```
output "buckets" {
  value = ["${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.bucket}"]
}

output "buckets_arns" {
  value = ["${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.arn}"]
}
```

Comment: Since Terraform 0.12 you can use a slightly more concise syntax
`output "buckets" {  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.bucket }`

Answer (score 1):

in most cases, it will give an error output value as empty tuple

join produces a string by concatenating together all elements of a given list of strings with the given delimiter.

The output of join is just a string, so this works fine (joining an empty list with an empty string as the separator creates an empty string). This type of thing was very common in tf0.11 configs:
example:

```
output "bucket_name" {
  value = join("", aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.*.id)
}
```

Though if you want the (pre-tf0.12.11) null behavior back instead, that will require the ternary operator:

```
output "bucket_name" {
  value = length(aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket) > 0 ? aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket[0].id : null
}
```

for list of outputs you can use the list formate.